# Google maps brings down performance, even after close

Tags: google-chrome, performance, google-maps

I'm using Ubuntu 12.

Google maps are very slow on my laptop, but even when I close browser (Chrome or Chromium), the performance goes down significantly. It stops every 3-4 seconds for about a second, so works in kind of jerks. This holds until I reboot. Wasn't able to find anything suspicious in system monitor, all four cores are used to <15%, memory usage is ~20%, so all far from full use. No any jumps as well, it just stops for a fraction of a second and gets back... And again and again.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Is you google map application up to date?

Comment: @mdpc What do you mean? I'm just accessing it though maps.google.com

Comment: I don't really know what the problem is, but I found that the new version of Google Maps acted like this...[swtiching to Classic Maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3045828?hl=en) fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions on [this page](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/enable-hardware-acceleration-in-chrome.html), I have seen a noticeable performance increase in my laptop (using ubuntu 12.04). In short:

1. Open chrome://flags
2. Enable Override software rendering list
3. Restart chromium